# Speed up Mysql queries with Hash Table in OPENSIPS

Tags: javascript, mysql, scripting, query-optimization, opensips

Dears,

I have got an Opensips server which make queries to an mysql server. I need to optimice these queries at maximum.

One way could be: using mysql table with engine=memory and index=hash, but ¿how to load these type of table at the init of the opensips server?

Another way: ¿is there a function in Opensips server to cache data of previous querys in order to recover them later?

Kind regards,
Tentenpie

Comment: If you are dealing with a table containing international prefix numbers, I assume there are no more than a couple of hundred entries. Why don't you load the hash table at program initialization?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry, i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Show the query you are running and the table structure(s). Also, what indexes do you have?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrefixPerCountry (
    Country CHAR(255),
 C_Prefix CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Prefix CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (C_Prefix)
)  ENGINE=MEMORY;

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_I_Prefixes ON PrefixPerCountry (C_Prefix) USING HASH;

Comment: Well, let me clarify: ¿how to init that table type 'Memory/hash' in my Opensips server   ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 2.2, OpenSIPS offers the [sql_cacher](https://opensips.org/html/docs/modules/3.0.x/sql_cacher.html) module.  You can use it in order to cache MySQL tables and achieve direct in-memory lookups for the keys of your choosing through the [$sql_cached_value](https://opensips.org/html/docs/modules/3.0.x/sql_cacher.html#pv_sql_cached_value) variable.

Cached tables are periodically refreshed according to the [reload_interval](https://opensips.org/html/docs/modules/3.0.x/sql_cacher.html#param_reload_interval) setting of the module.

If you consider sql_cacher to be too complex for your needs, then you can still maintain a high traffic throughput for your SIP proxy while also doing blocking MySQL queries by making all of these queries asynchronous, using the [async(avp_db_query())](https://opensips.org/html/docs/modules/3.0.x/avpops#afunc_avp_db_query) construct.

Comment: Thanks Liviu for your response. I am going to have a look to your very well linked docs in opensips and try a code for the purpose. Regards,